# Navigation dropdown toggle - mouseout as well as off hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone help me adapt the following so that the dropdown menu not only hides on click, but also hides on mouseout and/or when another of the top level menu buttons is hovered on?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QxRL9/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();
    });
});
```

Still getting my feet wet with jQuery/script coding.

NOTE: I'm using divs as part of the structure of the dropdown, as in the instance that "ul" above is replaced by a div.

FYI, I can't take credit for the above, it is the work of Pramod Sankar L (user PSL).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `$("li").on('click, mouseout', function(){`.. just commenting as I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li:has(ul)").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $('li > ul').hide();
    });
});
```

---

`$("li:has(ul)")` select `li` which contains `ul`

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Bwm5W/)

---

**Updated After Op's Comment**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dropmenu li:has(div)").click(function () {
        $('#dropmenu li.second-level > #dropmenu li.second-level div.drop_6col-bottom').not($(this).children("#dropmenu li.second-level div.drop_6col-bottom").toggle()).hide();
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).children('div').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmmm, this works on the fiddle, not on my dropdown. Going to have to find out what's up. Thanks, btw!!

Comment: @user3569292 is your site live or can you produce problem in fiddle ? Or is your menu loaded dynamically ?

Comment: @user3569292 your test page is working fine. What is not working according to you ?

Comment: @user3569292 Can u please tell me the exact problem ? What is not working .

Comment: I have set up the third level of navigation to appear on click (appears when you click on "Border", "Panel", etc). However, I want this third level to hide if I hover over the second level buttons ("Border", "Panel", etc). Otherwise, the third level "stacks" one on top of the other unless I click to close them.

Comment: @user3569292 Try code in the fiddle in your test page .. http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Bwm5W/2/

Comment: WONDERFUL! Thank you!!! How do I check the answer so that your last reply shows up as the solution?